# Web Driver (Selinium Version)

Tags: selenium, visualstudio

How to add the webdrivers of C# in VS 2005, I was tried the same but the "OpenQA" not found error is shown, 
Is there is any version problem?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest getting the latest Selenium2(webdriver) release from http://seleniumhq.org/download/

The following are the dll's needed to use webdriver in a solution

Add these from the package as a reference in your solution explorer:

webdriver.dll
Castle.Core.dll,
Ionic.Zip.dll,
Newtonsoft.Json.Net35.dll,
Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium.dll,
ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core.dll,
WebDriver.Support.dll,

Then use these using statements:

using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;

Comment: Agreed, this is how I do it!